# Not able to click on link in a div with background image only in ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hyperlink, click, background-image

Is it a known issue that ie does not like links placed in a div which has background image url set in css ? If I remove the background image from the div, then all is well.

I have a few such links which works perfectly well in Chrome and Firefox.

Would be great if somebody can enlighten me on the issue.

My code

css

```
.header{margin:0 auto;
    background:url('images/highres/bg1.jpg') no-repeat center;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/highres/bg1.jpg', sizingMethod='scale') no-repeat;
    -ms-filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/highres/bg1.jpg',sizingMethod='scale') no-repeat  
    width:1280px;height:650px;
    background-size:cover;
    margin:0 auto;padding:0;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;font-height:0.8em;
z-index:20; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="header">
            <div style="float:left"><a href='file.php'>Link 1</a></div>
            <div style="float:right"><a href='file.php'>Link 2</a></div>
            <div style="margin:0 auto"><a href='file.php'>Link 3</a></div>
 </div>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do the links work when you remove the background image?

Comment: @Kellen, yes they do

Comment: Are you using IE 11? For any personal work, I do not support IE. IE usage is very low, and it continues to drop at a steady rate. Here are some stats. https://www.w3schools.com/Browsers/browsers_explorer.asp Its usage is probably much lower, excluding corporations, running dated systems/software. That said, if you're developing for an organization, still running IE, you could utilize some JS to detect if IE is being used. If IE is detected, you could overwrite the background image property by injecting css with the JS function. See JS browser hacks here: http://browserhacks.com/

Comment: @Kellen Well that's real input. Thanks. That's what I wanted to know. I am using IE 8.  I thought it was my incompetence in html/css coding due to which I get this error. I too hate IE. But since I believe there still is some sizeable population in my country (India) using this Ogre and its primitive versions, I thought I might as well get my site  performing in IE too.  Well looks like its a lost cause..or rather a useless cause...

Comment: @user3526204 i put this code in a fiddle and it worked fine on ie11 https://jsfiddle.net/ghc7f6ju/ the only difference was that i added targets, but i do that in jsfiddle so that the fiddle window doesn't disappear..

Comment: @RachelGallen Then I guess it is a version issue. Then I am gonna have to   get some version hacks ... :( Actually, having an image inside the div filling it and then placing the links  over it with absolute positioning, works. But I didn't want to use absolute positioning.  Anyway, I do have a permanent alert on the screen saying that the site is best viewed in Chrome and Firefox when the page detects IE (as Kellen mentioned). Guess I have to settle for it.